# What impact does a large purchase with an immediate payoff have on a cashback reward and credit score?

Tags: credit-card, credit-score

I want to purchase a laptop worth $1300. If I buy it using the credit card, I will get 5% cashback. I will pay immediately to the credit card company after the purchase (I do have that much money in my bank account). Will I be charged interest on the purchase? Will it affect my credit score?

Comment: Any link to get your credit card ?

Comment: What card is giving you 5%?  I want that card.  Only one I can think of is Target card for purchases at Target.

Comment: Also as an aside, it's worth checking into other benefits such as a warranty.  I bought a laptop on an AMEX card a few years ago and it went kaput, but they sprung for a new laptop after I submitted a repair invoice (which was naturally more than a cost of a new laptop) because there was warranty provision.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44824/discussion-on-question-by-ksank43-purchasing-laptop-with-credit-card).

Comment: @coburne Amazon also has a 5% back card for Amazon purchases.

Comment: Jean: Discover provides such credit cards.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Credit cards are meant to be used so generally it doesn't hurt your credit score to use them.  To top it off you even get an interest grace period so you don't have to rush home and pay balances as soon as they're charged.

In general you accrue charges during your statement period, we'll call it September 1 through September 30.  The statement due date is something like 20 days after the close of the statement period, so we'll call it October 20.  As long as you habitually pay your entire statement balance by the due date you will never pay interest.  You charge your laptop on September 3, it shows up on your statement as $1,300, you pay $1,300 on October 18, you pay no interest.

However, if you pay $1,000 on October 18 leaving a $300 balance to be carried in to the next statement period (a carried balance) you will pay interest.  Generally interest is calculated based on your average daily balance during the statement period, which is now be the October 1 to October 31 period.  You'll notice that you didn't pay anything until the October 18, that means the entire $1,300 will be included in your average daily balance up to the 18th of the month.  Add to that, anything else you charge on the card now will be included in your average daily balance for interest charge calculation purposes.

The moral of the story is, use your card, and pay your entire statement balance before the due date.

Now how much will this impact your credit score?  It's tough to say.  Utilization is not a bad thing until it's a big number.  I've read that 70% utilization and over is really the point at which lenders will raise an eyebrow and under 30% is considered excellent. If you have one card and $1,300 is a significant portion of your available limit, then yes you should probably pay it down quickly.  Spend six or so months using the card and paying it, then call your bank and ask for a credit line increase.

Comment: Note that [utilization is a very temporary factor](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/22107/15119) and is not tracked historically. As long as you don't need to pull your score in the next couple of months it's not worth worrying about.

Comment: 70% utilization is really quite high.

Comment: @stannius: I used to run at 90% utilization due to my habit of not taking more credit than I need. Now my bank keeps bumping up the maximum on my card without actually asking me. Not that I have to care anymore.

Comment: @Joshua the utilization police always come out for credit card questions.

Answer (score 16):

5% cashback? Wow.

No, this would not generally affect your credit rating. You aren't altering anything that is generally tracked by the credit rating agencies. You put a purchase on your credit card which temporarily increases your utilisation, but then immediately pay it off, leaving your utilisation practically unchanged.

Comment: Discover currently has Amazon as one of its 5% categories, so this is easier than you'd think.

Comment: My Amex card gives 5% back on all purchases at office supply stores. (In US, Staples, Office Depot/Max)

Comment: I get 5% back on my Chase card at Amazon (Visa) It's not unheard of.

Comment: is it 5% @ Amazon all year, or is quarterly?

Comment: @coburne [Discover](https://www.discover.com/credit-cards/cashback-bonus/cashback-calendar.html) is quarterly (Same with [Chase Freedom](https://creditcards.chase.com/freedom/calendarreminder), but different quarter, this year's last quarter categories are not out yet). I persume the Amex is all year. Chase has a [Amazon cobranded card](https://www.chase.com/credit-cards/amazon/amazon-home) which gives 3%, there may be other chase cards that give 5%. Amazon has a [store card](https://www.amazon.com/iss/credit/storecardmember/ref=footer_plcc?_encoding=UTF8) that gives 5%.

Comment: @coburne: I know of one that gives 5% @ Amazon all year, but (a) it is no longer offered, and (b) it only works for purchases from Amazon itself, not from Amazon Marketplace etc.

Comment: @Mehrdad If you an Amazon Prime member, then Amazon's store credit line gives you 5% cash back all the time.

Comment: @Dev: Interesting, but that's like having a card with an annual fee, which kind of pays back for that...

Comment: @Mehrdad - no doubt, that's one way to look at it. On the other hand as an existing prime customer happy to pay $99 a year for the benefits it provides, the card is simply another perk that will save me enough money to make my prime membership free.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: The thing is, you have to spend nearly $2k/year on Amazon just to break even with the annual fee and get 0% cash back. Unless you have business expenses or buy something, that's already a *lot*. But if you want to match e.g. Citi's 2% card, you have to spend $3.3k/year on Amazon... which is even *more* a **lot**. Do you really spend that much on Amazon just for home expenses? If you do, I can see it making sense, but I have a hard time swallowing the idea that most people with Prime reach this *every* year...

Comment: @Mehrdad I was already a prime member when I applied for the line of credit. Prime has a lot of features, you wouldn't pick up prime just for the 5% that wouldn't make sense. If you buy things from amazon often enough you'll break even on the shipping alone not accounting for the 5%.

Comment: @Mehrdad - as Dev suggests, the Prime account is already of value to me. I don't have the card yet, but it's on my to do list. It's not tough to blow through $2000/yr. (Probably time to move to chat if you want to talk more.)

Comment: @Mehrdad - [Room for discussion on this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44861/room-for-joetaxpayer-and-mehrdad)